Equivalence relation on Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$
I need help understanding a proof: I need help proving that Cauchy Sequences form an equivalence relation if and only if they are equivalent
I have two questions:

Is it necessary to use the absolute value? I had to do the same (or at least very similar) assignment for university but we defined the equivalence relation as $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim (b_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} :\Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - b_n) = 0$. Would it also suffice to simply show for transitivity: $a_n - c_n = a_n - b_n + b_n - c_n$ and thus the limit is: $\lim(a_n - c_n) = \lim(a_n - b_n + b_n - c_n) = \lim(a_n - b_n) + \lim(b_n - c_n) = 0$ by the properties of the limit?

Another question (not directly related to the link): We also showed well-definedness of addition and mulitplication. Would it be okay to do it like this: We know that $(a_n) \sim (a^\ast_n)$ and $(b_n) \sim (b^\ast_n)$ then that is equivalent to the equivalency classes being the same and hence we can simply plug in $[(a^\ast_n)] + [(b^\ast_n)] = [(a_n)] + [(b_n)]$ and addition is already defined such that $[(a_n)] + [(b_n)] := [(a_n) + (b_n)]$. Thus $[(a^\ast_n) + (b^\ast_n)] = [(a_n) + (b_n)]$ which was to be shown. Similarly for multiplication.


My solutions are probably not valid (since they seem too easy) so it would be very appreciated if someone told me where I'm confused.


Is it necessary to use the absolute value?

In this case, not really.
Normally, in a metric space $\newcommand{\seq}[1]{\left\{ #1_n \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}} (X,d)$ [1], we define convergence of a sequence $\seq x \subseteq X$ to a limit $x \in X$ by
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,x) = 0
$$
For $\mathbb{R}$, we typically give it the distance
$$
d(x,y) := |x-y|
$$
so using absolute values is a direct appeal to that definition.
However, since in $\mathbb{R}$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0
\iff
\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = 0
$$
we may drop the absolute values just fine, since we're concerned with a real limit going to $0$.
(Exercise: Prove this!)


Would it also suffice to simply show for transitivity: $a_n - c_n = a_n - b_n + b_n - c_n$ and thus the limit is: $\lim(a_n - c_n) = \lim(a_n - b_n + b_n - c_n) = \lim(a_n - b_n) + \lim(b_n - c_n) = 0$ by the properties of the limit?

Yes, but be sure you know what properties are actually being used. Namely, why can you split the limit across the sums - it's because you know the two individual limits converge by hypothesis.



Another question (not directly related to the link): We also showed well-definedness of addition and mulitplication. Would it be okay to do it like this: We know that $(a_n) \sim (a^*_n)$ and $(b_n) \sim (b^*_n)$ then that is equivalent to the equivalency classes being the same and hence we can simply plug in $[(a^*_n)] + [(b^*_n)] = [(a_n)] + [(b_n)]$ and addition is already defined such that $[(a_n)] + [(b_n)] := [(a_n) + (b_n)]$. Thus $[(a^*_n) + (b^*_n)] = [(a_n) + (b_n)]$ which was to be shown. Similarly for multiplication.


This, I feel, merits a justification, namely, how are you sure that
$$
[(a^*_n) + (b^*_n)] = [(a_n) + (b_n)]
$$
holds? $(a_n^\ast)$ and $(a_n)$ are different objects - perhaps lying in the same equivalence class as seen, but now you're manipulating the sequences themselves.
So, what you need to show is that the sequences $\seq{a_n+b}$ and $\seq{a_n^\ast + b^\ast}$ lie in the same equivalence class.


My solutions are probably not valid (since they seem too easy) so it would be very appreciated if someone told me where I'm confused.

Introductory classes in set theory and analysis can sometimes be like that. Sometimes an item/proof is super obvious; sometimes there's some obscure counterexample to a seemingly-true statement. A good technique I was taught was to question everything possible: if you're justifying something with the words "clearly" or "obviously" in a homework at this pivotal level, there's a good chance you're (unintentionally) sweeping some rigor under the rug. Make sure that if any logical step or equality or whatever is poked at, you can justify it in as much detail as need be.
(Within reason of course. You'll get a feel down the road for the things you can handwave in class in the interest of brevity. No one will expect you to justify $2+2=4$ ... probably ...)

Footnotes/Asides:
[1] - A metric space is a pair of a set $X$ and a metric function $d : X \times X \to [0,\infty)$. The point of $d$ is to encapsulate a notion of "distance" - $d(x,y)$ being the distance between $x$ and $y$ - and we do that by saying $d$ must satisfy the following axioms:

Symmetry: $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x,y$
Triangle Inequality: $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z$
Positive Definite: $d(x,y) = 0 \iff x=y$

Any vector space $V$ with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ is an example of a metric space, with distance
$$
d(x,y) := \|x-y\|
$$

Thank you for the answer. Again I have two questions: Since the Cauchy sequences lie in $\mathbb{Q}$ I know that I can‘t automatically assume that they are convergent (I only know the differences are). But I‘m not using that I think they are when I add zero like I did above, right? And also for your answer to my second question:   The hypothesis was that $[(a_n)] \sim [(a^*_n)]$ (same for $b_n$) and addition was defined in my assignment as “pulling together“ these two equivalency classes like I did. So why can‘t I (by hypothesis) interchange the representatives and then use the definition?
